# Joining two simple tables using nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join two tables that look like this:

```
Table A
ID  X
1   0
1   8

Table B
ID  Y
1   0
1   24
1   48
```

Into something that looks like this:

```
Table D
ID    X     Y
1     0     0
1     8     24
1     NULL  48
```

Or even this will work:

```
Table C
ID    X     Y
1     0     NULL
1     8     NULL
1     NULL  0 
1     NULL  24 
1     NULL  48
```

But this:

```
SELECT a.ID, X, Y FROM [Table A] a
LEFT JOIN [Table] b ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE a.ID = 1
GROUP BY a.ID, X, Y
```

Keeps giving me this:

```
Table X
ID    X     Y
1     0     0
1     0     24
1     0     48
1     8     24 
1     8     48
```

Comment: The result you are getting doesn't match what I get if I do it myself: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30dc0/4/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will give the solution with nulls:

```
SELECT ID, X, null as Y FROM "Table A"
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, null X, Y FROM "Table B"
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Interesting, did the charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `union all`.

```
select id,x,null y from tablea
union all
select id,null,y from tableb
```

or a `full join`.

```
select a.id,a.x,b.y 
from tablea a
full join tableb b on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: That `UNION ALL` gets me what I need, except I get no column name for the `y` column...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ROWNUM and CTEs:

```
WITH 
ra AS
 (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID,X) AS row,id,x FROM a)
,rb AS
 (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID,Y) as row,id,y FROM b)

SELECT COALESCE(ra.id,rb.id),x,y
FROM ra
INNER JOIN rb
ON ra.id = rb.id AND ra.row = rb.row
```